# Generic 'temporary instance' class

Tags: c#, generics, weak-references

I've been reading about `WeakPointer` and `WeakPointer<T>` today, and it looks very useful.  Rather than just using it as-is though, I decided to write a wrapper around it that covers a common usage case for me.

Code as follows:

```
public class Temporary<T> where T : class
{
    Func<T> generator = null;
    WeakReference<T> reference = null;

    public T Value 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return GetValue(); 
        } 
    }

    public Temporary(T value)
        : this(value, null)
    { }

    public Temporary(Func<T> generator)
        : this(null, generator)
    { }

    public Temporary(T value, Func<T> generator)
    {
        reference = new WeakReference<T>(value);
        this.generator = generator;
    }

    public T GetValue()
    {
        if (reference == null)
            return null;
        T res;
        if (!reference.TryGetTarget(out res) && generator != null)
        {
            res = generator();
            reference.SetTarget(res);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

I've tested this against my use-case and it works as I expect - the garbage collector cleans out items with no active references, and they are re-instantiated at need.

I'm looking for critiques of the implementation and suggestions for improvements/additions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty good, clean and simple code. Not a lot to critique really. A few minor things:

1. Some people (myself included) prefer to prefix private fields with `_`. This way it's easy to see that it's a field rather than a local variable (and gets rid of the `this.` in most cases).
2. You shouldn't have a public property and a public method which do the same thing. How is a programer supposed to know whether to use `Value` or `GetValue`? It's not obvious what the difference is or if there is one at all.
3. Not 100% sure about the `null` check in `GetValue()`. There is no code path where `reference` should ever be `null`. So it would actually indicate a bug if it were the case which you are hiding with this check. Consider removing the check or actually throwing an `InvalidOperationException` or similar instead. Detecting bugs early is important. Another option would be to look at [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) to state the invariants of that method.
4. I have started to try and avoid `null` checks where possible by making sure that there is always an object. In your case this could be something like this:

   ```
   public class Temporary<T> where T : class
   {
       private static Func<T> NullGenerator = () => null;

       Func<T> generator = NullGenerator;
       WeakReference reference = null;

       public T Value
       {
           get
           {
               return GetValue();
           }
       }

       public Temporary(T value)
           : this(value, NullGenerator)
       { }

       public Temporary(Func<T> generator)
           : this(null, generator)
       { }

       public Temporary(T value, Func<T> generator)
       {
           if (generator == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("generator");
           reference = new WeakReference(value);
           this.generator = generator;
       }

       private T GetValue()
       {
           T res;
           if (!reference.TryGetTarget(out res))
           {
               res = generator();
               reference.SetTarget(res);
           }
           return res;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm not sure about `NullGenerator`, it makes the code simpler, but I also think it makes it less clear. The explicit check against `null` in the original version is very clear.

Comment: +1 for the null generator and rewriting GetValue() around nulls.  Exactly what I would have said.  That null check on reference was certainly a bug.  Also, could not agree more with item 2.

Comment: Good answer Chris.  The `reference == null` check was a leftover from when I was thinking about implementing `IDisposable`, but it should `throw` if there's a problem with the reference.  I agree with @svick about the NullGenerator, but the rest of your points are excellent.